# Crystal Reports not putting a record on the page

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a very odd error with a report. There is one record in the record set returned to the report that is not printing on the page. When I copy the SQL statement and run it directly in SQL Server Management Studio, the row is there so I know it isn't in the selection formula. That also tells me table/view linking is correct (although I double checked that as well). I have gone through all of the grouping levels and looked at suppression settings and group sorting. Essentially, I have exhausted all options that I can find that would be causing this record to be suppressed and can't find anywhere that it would be suppressed or hidden from view. I haven't seen this behavior ever in 22 years of working with Crystal.

Any ideas of what may be causing one record to be suppressed while all others around it are still visible? I'm on version 2013, support pack 4 (14.1.4.13274). I would prefer not to rebuild this report from scratch if I can avoid it but I'm very close to the edge on this one.

Query as requested:

SELECT "KENNEL"."KENNEL_NO", "KENNEL"."ANIMAL_ID", "KENNEL"."TAG_NO", "ANIMAL"."YEARS_OLD", "ANIMAL"."MONTHS_OLD", "ANIMAL"."ANIMAL_ID", "ANIMAL"."PRIMARY_BREED", "ANIMAL"."SECONDARY_BREED", "ANIMAL"."PRIMARY_COLOR", "ANIMAL"."SECONDARY_COLOR", "ANIMAL"."ANIMAL_TYPE", "KENNEL"."OUTCOME_DATE_NULL", "v_tx_feed_sheet"."visit_type", "v_tx_feed_sheet"."resolved_date", "v_tx_feed_sheet"."visit_date", "v_tx_feed_sheet"."CONDITION_TYPE", "v_tx_feed_sheet"."TREATMENT_DESC", "dfl_kennel_groupings"."Ani_Loc_Sub", "dfl_kennel_groupings"."Ani_Loc", "KENNEL"."OUTCOME_TYPE", "KENNEL"."OUTCOME_SUBTYPE", "KENNEL"."OUTCOME_DATE", "v_tx_feed_sheet"."CYCLE", "v_tx_feed_sheet"."MEDICATION", "v_tx_feed_sheet"."NUM_DAYS", "dfl_kennel_groupings"."Offsite_Knl", "KENNEL"."INTAKE_DATE", "KENNEL"."REASON", "ANIMAL"."age_now", "ANIMAL"."DOB"
 FROM   (("ANIMAL"."SYSADM"."KENNEL" "KENNEL" INNER JOIN "ANIMAL"."SYSADM"."dfl_kennel_groupings" "dfl_kennel_groupings" ON "KENNEL"."KENNEL_NO"="dfl_kennel_groupings"."Kennel_No") LEFT OUTER JOIN "ANIMAL"."SYSADM"."ANIMAL" "ANIMAL" ON "KENNEL"."ANIMAL_ID"="ANIMAL"."ANIMAL_ID") LEFT OUTER JOIN "ANIMAL"."SYSADM"."v_tx_feed_sheet" "v_tx_feed_sheet" ON "KENNEL"."ANIMAL_ID"="v_tx_feed_sheet"."ANIMAL_ID"
 WHERE  "ANIMAL"."ANIMAL_TYPE"='DOG' AND "KENNEL"."KENNEL_NO" NOT  LIKE 'DHA%' AND  NOT ("KENNEL"."KENNEL_NO"='HOME' OR "KENNEL"."KENNEL_NO"='LOST') AND "KENNEL"."KENNEL_NO" LIKE 'B%' AND "dfl_kennel_groupings"."Offsite_Knl"='N' AND (("KENNEL"."OUTCOME_DATE_NULL"='Y' AND ((("v_tx_feed_sheet"."resolved_date">={ts '1899-12-30 00:00:00'} AND "v_tx_feed_sheet"."resolved_date"<{ts '1899-12-30 00:00:00'})) OR ("v_tx_feed_sheet"."resolved_date" IS  NULL ))) OR ("KENNEL"."OUTCOME_DATE_NULL"='Y' AND "ANIMAL"."YEARS_OLD"=0 AND "ANIMAL"."MONTHS_OLD"<=4) OR ("ANIMAL"."ANIMAL_TYPE"='DOG' AND "KENNEL"."OUTCOME_SUBTYPE" LIKE 'SURG%' AND ("KENNEL"."OUTCOME_DATE">={ts '2017-04-26 00:00:00'} AND "KENNEL"."OUTCOME_DATE"<{ts '2017-04-27 00:00:00'})) OR ("ANIMAL"."ANIMAL_TYPE"='DOG' AND "KENNEL"."OUTCOME_SUBTYPE" LIKE 'SURG%' AND ("KENNEL"."OUTCOME_DATE">={ts '2017-04-27 00:00:00'} AND "KENNEL"."OUTCOME_DATE"<{ts '2017-04-28 00:00:00'})) OR ("ANIMAL"."ANIMAL_TYPE"='DOG' AND ("KENNEL"."INTAKE_DATE">={ts '2017-04-27 00:00:00'} AND "KENNEL"."INTAKE_DATE"<{ts '2017-04-28 00:00:00'}))) AND  NOT ("KENNEL"."REASON"='DOA' OR "KENNEL"."REASON"='EUTH' OR "KENNEL"."REASON"='EUTH BEHAV' OR "KENNEL"."REASON"='EUTH ILL' OR "KENNEL"."REASON"='EUTH OLD' OR "KENNEL"."REASON"='EUTH OTHER' OR "KENNEL"."REASON"='EUTH YOUNG')

Comment: How are you filling the data of the report? Is the report connecting to the database using an internal query or are you filling the data at code.

Comment: Just pulling fields out of the two tables and two views.

Comment: i can't figure out what your doing.. maybe you can show some additional details here.

Comment: can you go to Database Menu > Show SQL Query and paste it here

Comment: I have edited my original question since a comment is too short but as I mentioned, the query is not the problem. When I run this in SSMS, the records all return as expected.